# Inlining inside a class

Tags: c++, inline

I have a templated class where most methods are defined inside the class so they can be inlined. In the following example, I show a copy constructor, but it could be anything.

```
template <typename T>
class Vector {
private:
    ...
public:
    Vector(const Vector& v) {
        if (condition) {
            call_1(...);
        } else {
            call_2(...);
        }
    }
};
```

In this constructor, `condition` is almost always true, therefore I want to give the compiler all the hints so it inlines `call_1` but not `call_2` (I want to prevent code bloat). I have two questions:

1. At first, I was thinking to define `call_1` and `call_2` as methods for the object and define `call_1` inside the class and `call_2` outside the class. Is there anything else I could do to help the compiler?
2. What can I do if I want `call_1` and `call_2` to be shared by many different classes and therefore define them as functions outside the class?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you determined through profiling that the inliner's choice make a measurable difference in your code? If not, well...

Comment: @Mat: I did not. But let's think of something such as push_back in a std::vector. Most of the time, what is does is an assignment and moving a pointer. From time to time, it involves allocating some memory, copying a lot of stuff and then do the assignment and move a pointer. My guess is that inlining the part where you allocate and copy all that stuff is not a good idea. Most likely, it will waste the L1 data cache.

Comment: If you use clang or gcc, you could use `__builtin_expect(expr, likely)`, where `expr` is your `condition` and `likely` is either 1 or 0 for "this is likely to be true" or "this is likely to be false". This will tell the compiler to optimise for the more likely case. Unfortunately, MSVC doesn't have an equivalent option.

Comment: Mats: I am using gcc, clang, icpc and Visual Studio so I am looking at something more portable. But, thank you very much for the hint.

Comment: Note however that L1 instruction [not DATA as you write] cache will only load code that is in cache-lines that the processor executes (or thinks it will execute if it uses branch-prediction to pre-load caches), so as long as the code is sufficiently large that it takes more than a single cache-line, it will most likely just lead to code-bloat, not actual waste of L1 cache-space.

Comment: Mats: I agree. So code bloat would not affect performance in that case?

Comment: Mats: If you look at libc++, the push_back method calls `__push_back_slow_path(__x);` when reallocation has to be done. The name suggests that it is done for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are some different aspects of this.

1. Code bloat in general - code that doesn't get executed very often should not be added as inline code to general code-paths that are executed regularly.
2. Letting the compiler know that some paths are more likely than others.

Let's look a bit more at the details of the general code-bloat first. It causes bigger executables, which is generally not a good thing. But the performance overhead is relatively small - it is more a case of size of the whole executable is unecessarily large if every single instance of `vector<T>.push_back` contains the same large bit of code (in a large application, `push_back` may be called thousands of times [my 11k lines of compiler has some 70-odd calls, and it's not even using vectors very much], and adding a few dozen instructions will of course cause the whole application to be significantly larger. So there is definitely value in not inlining the code.

The second aspect is important for the compilers ability to "make the right decision". Simply declaring a function outside of the class MAY help, but unless the compiler also knows that it's unlikely to happen, there is no guarantee the compiler does not inline the function that is reflecting the unusual case.

However, on the technical side, your only portable choice is to move the function out of the class definition. That is the only way to at least hint to the compiler that it's not a suitable candidate for inlining. But compilers are sometimes deciding that "it's worth inlining this code anyway", and it being template code, you can't really do the old trick of "let's put the code in a source file that isn't compiled together with the caller.

Using macros that expand to `__builtin_expect(expr, likely)` where `expr` is your condition, and `likely` the "common outcome" (`0` for `false` and `1` for `true`). Unfortunately, this is not available in Microsoft compilers. You may also want explore the option of a macro that expands to "do not inline" e.g. GCC's `__attribute__((noinline))` to force the code to not be inlined.

Using profile-driven optimisation and related annotations, which is available in most advanced compilers, and this will make the compiler choose the right optionse.

For question 2, it can be hard to do this generically - writing some general purpose code MAY work, such as:

```
template<T>
T* grow_allocation(T* existing, size_t cur_size, size_t new_size)
{
    T* new_alloc = new T[new_size];
    // There is probably clever stuff like std::copy and std::move
    // that is "better" than this - writing basic loops to clearly
    // show what is being done.
    for(size_t i = 0; i < cur_size; i++)
    {
        new_alloc[i] = existing[i]; 
    }
    for(size_t i = cur_size; i < new_size; i++)
    {
        new_alloc[i] = T();
    }
    // Probably need to deal with "new_size < cur_size" and destroy
    // those too... 
}
```

Now you could call this function from all places that have a dynamically allocated region of memory to hold objects of type `T`. [That are trivially constructable]

Comment: Mats: Thanks for your really nice answer on question 1. Do you have any advice on question 2?

Comment: @InsideLoop: Added an answer to Q2 too.

Comment: Your answer does not address the inlining / non-inlining problem.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the question with regards to Q2 was "how do I write some code that can be shared between several classes?" - and the answer here is simply to make it a free function, outside of any class [possibly in a suitable namespace and/or separate class as a static function or something to avoid name polution]. If you want it to be inlined, make sure it's small and perhaps use the `inline` keyword, but it's really no guarantee that the compiler will/won't inline based on keywords [or placement in/out of class]

Comment: Mats: No real portable solution. That was my guess. Thank you very very much. I'll use in/out of class as much as I can, also inline. If it is not enough, I assume profile guided optimisation will figure it out.

Comment: There CAN be other tricks too, but it will be more specific to a particular problem - but it would seem from the code I've looked at that using out-of-class definition is "good enough" for most things. Portable solutions here are very hard to find, since it's all about telling the compiler stuff that isn't really part of the standard [likelyhood of banches, inline/don't inline this function are not part of the C++ language]

Answer (score 0):

Regardin

> Is there anything else I could do to help the compiler?

If `condition` is known at compile time, you can use two constructors:

```
Vector(const Vector& v, std::true_type) {
   call_1(...);
}

Vector(const Vector& v, std::false_type) {
   call_2(...);
}
```

Regarding

> What can I do if I want `call_1` and `call_2` to be shared by many different objects and therefore define them as functions outside the class?

I think you mean *many different classes* when you say *many different objects*. Choices that I can think of:

1. Make `call_1` and `call_2` global functions and call them from all the classes. This approach makes sense if the classes that use them can't be thought of as having a common base type.
2. Make a common base class and put the functions in the base class. Call them from the derived classes. This approach makes sense only if the base class derived class relationship makes sense.

Comment: R Sahu: The condition is not known at compile time.

Comment: @InsideLoop, then, what you have is the best one can do.